# Correctness of using std::find this way

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some structure like this:

```
struct SomeStruct{
/* ...various members */
std::string some_data;
bool operator==(const std::string& s) { return s==some_data; }
};
```

And at some point, I have used the `std::find` function on an iterable container (namely `std::vector`) like this:

```
auto it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), std::string(some_string));
```

where `v` is a `std::vector<SomeStruct>`. As the `operator==` is defined for the two types (`SomeStruct` and `std::string`), it does work for me, but I would like to know whether it is correct or the behaviour of the function in this case is implementation-dependent. In any case, I guess I should have used `std::find_if` with a custom predicate (maybe a lambda function), right?

Comment: It's not a mistake that it works for you, if that's what you're asking. It's correct/intended behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct behavior. However, unless you really want `SomeStruct` to be equitable to a `std::string` in all other contexts, using the `==` implementation to enable `std::find` may not be the best solution.

A better approach would be using [`find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) with a lambda:

```
auto it = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [&] (const SomeStruct& s) {
    return s.some_data==some_string;
});
```

This way the string-to-SomeStruct comparison is explicit, and is limited in its scope to finding by `some_data`.

Answer (score 0):

From the C++11 standard 25.2.5

> Returns: The first iterator i in the range [first,last) for which the following corresponding conditions hold: *i == value[...]

So the intended behavior of the function is to use the `==` operator.  As long as the types has on then the function will work.  If you do not have an `==` operator then you would need to use the overload that takes a predicate and do the comparison in the predicate.